# Looking for a PIC board with webserver

Tags: pic, programming, picaxe, tcp-ip

I am looking for a PIC which has a webserver builtin or has the ability to install one(with) . I want to experiment connecting  in reasonable price please)two PIC/PICAXE boards or different type and send data from one to another. I will be running a server program in the webserver where I want to capture the data sent from 2nd PIC board.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some links:

[Dangerous Prototypes web platform](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Web_Platform)

[Web platform v1.1 Assembled](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Web-platform-v1-1-Assembled-p-582.html)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Any PIC18+ can run the Microchip TCP/IP stack which includes a web server and is a free download from their website.  All you need is a PIC based dev board with ethernet circuitry.

[Microchip sells a few such dev boards directly](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2807&devicefamilyid=2231&page=wwwdevWiredConnectivity), they also have some wifi boards.

There may also be some third party dev boards that are cheaper, I have no experience with those however, I've only works with the ones straight from uC.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest and cheapest solution for you is this product:  [EZ Web Lynx](http://www.ezweblynx.com/)